# Button in UITableView hierarchy UITest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

Could you help me? It doesn't work and I don't know why?

[image]

Comment: If you run your test, is the button you try to tap on, visible on the screen? Do you get any error messages, or logs?

Comment: Yes, it's visible. I don't get any error, but button will be never tapped.

Comment: in debug Mode Can you please try "po app.buttons["YourbuttonName"].hittable/exists/". Then check the result if it is returning false or true. Then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to whether or not this is intended by Apple or not, but Xcode UI tests will not find any view inside the hierarchy `UITableView` > `UIView`.

The only way to see views inside a `UITableView` is to have the table contain `UITableViewCell`(s), and add whatever views you like inside the cell.

Putting any view other than a cell directly inside a table view will result in any elements contained within the non-cell view not being visible to the UI tests.